# DXA .Net Web App Upgrade Issue from 2.0.3 to 2.2

Tags: dxa, dxa2.2, sites-9.5, .net

When I try to update the nuget package for Sdl.Web.Delivery (8.5.1041 to 11.5.1045) I get an error:

```
Unable to find a version of 'StackExchange.Redis.StrongName' that is compatible with 'Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Redis 2.2.0 constraint: StackExchange.Redis.StrongName (>= 1.2.6)'
```

When I try to upgrade the StackExchange.Redis.StrongName (1.1.605 to 1.2.6) which by the way is Deprecated I get the following error:

```
Unable to resolve dependencies. 'Sdl.ECommerce.Formatting 1.2.0-preview-24' is not compatible with 'Sdl.ECommerce.Dxa 1.2.0-preview-31 constraint: Sdl.ECommerce.Formatting (>= 1.2.0)'
```

Comment: It was not a tridion issue , customer fixed the issue by updating the dependency and also .net version